# Error searching for packages. Ошибка с поиском пакета в unity

Tags: unity3d

В пакетном менеджере юнити не выдает ассеты добавленные с Unity asset store. В консоли выходит две ошибки:

1. [Package Manager Window] Cannot perform upm operation: Unable to perform online search:
   Request [POST https://api.unity.com/v1/oauth2/token] failed. One or more invalid parameters was given. [InvalidParameter].
   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
2. [Package Manager Window] Error searching for packages.
   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()

email аккаунта потвержден, много в сети нашел похожих проблем, конкретно мою они не решили..

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась полной переустановкой unity и соответствующих пакетов.